# Remove special characters and convert vowels with accent marks to vowels without accent marks in CakePHP slugs

Tags: php, cakephp, special-characters, slug, cakephp-1.2

I need two improvements for my slugs:

> 1. Removing special characters.
> 2. Converting vowels with accent marks to vowels without accent marks.

The problem is that my website is generating URLs with slugs such as:

[https://example.net/Toronto/product/férula-dental-limpieza-con-ul](https://example.net/Toronto/product/f%C3%A9rula-dental-limpieza-con-ul)

[https://cuponclub.net/Toronto/product/lifting-de-pestañas](https://cuponclub.net/Toronto/product/lifting-de-pesta%C3%B1as)

Those special characters such as "é" and "ñ" in the URL tend to be problematic for me for many different reasons such as when I integrate URLs to APIs that I use or even when sharing links...

I am using `CakePHP 1.2`. This is how I implement the slugs in the code:

```
class Product extends AppModel{
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    var $actsAs = array(
        'Sluggable' => array(
            'label' => array(
                'short_name'
            ),
            'length' => 30,
            'overwrite' => false
        )
    );
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
}
```

In the database, `'short_name'` is the field that is used to generate the slug. Without CakePHP, PHP already provides built-in functions such as `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` and by using those functions and a regular expresion such as `[^A-Za-z0-9\-]`, I could remove all special characters after replacing all spaces with hyphens. But since I am using `CakePHP`, I need to use its syntax. I was reading https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-sluggable-plugin and I found this information about the `label`:

> label : (array | string, optional) set to the field name that contains
>   the string from where to generate the slug, or a set of field names to
>   concatenate for generating the slug. DEFAULTS TO: title

Can I treat `label` as a string and apply functions such as `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` to it?

Comment: Hi, CakePHP doesn't prevent you at all from using PHP functions`. If you find a replacement for them in CakePHP it's ok to use or else you can use PHP built in functions in my opinion.

Comment: "Can I treat label as a string" Did you try?

Comment: @ankabout I know CakePHP allows me to use PHP functions. It is just that https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-sluggable-plugin is a CakePHP plugin and I cannot use PHP functions at my will, but I need to respect the syntax of the plugin.

Comment: Just create your own behavior, or modify the 3rd party one that you are using (it hasn't had any update in _10 years_, so you won't miss out on anything when maintaining it yourself). Also look into using [**PHPs transliteration functionality**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php).

Comment: @ndm I like the idea of modifying app/models/behaviors/sluggable.php. Looking at that file, it was generated on 2009-10-16 13:36:57. The author is Mariano Iglesias. I read one of his books and he is well-known in the CakePHP community. But according to https://github.com/mariano/syrup/tree/master/models/behaviors, his sluggable.php was last modified 9 years ago! I sounds like I should be maintaining this 3rd. party file myself and I will not be missing out on anything as you said.

Comment: @miken32 I am doing some further research first.

Comment: @ndm You can go ahead and write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and have this question marked as resolved. I like the approach of modifying sluggable.php and maintaining it myself considering that it is and old plugin/behavior that has not been updated by the original creator for years now. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just using the documented [Tools.Slugged behavior](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Behavior/Slugged.md) from the awesome-list and backport the 2.x version of it if you have an older framework version running?

Comment: @mark I did not know about Tools.Slugged behavior and that sounds like a good option to backport it to the version of CakePHP that I am using. Good to have many options. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the plugin that you are using hasn't had any updates in the last 10 years, I would say it's safe to assume that maintaining it yourself is your best option - if you don't want to [**create a behavior from scratch**](https://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Behaviors.html#creating-behaviors) that is, wich shouldn't be very hard to do either

So, just fork it and make the required changes or create a custom behavior. I would also suggest to have a look at how the latest CakePHP handles this, see the source for [**`\Cake\Utility\Text::slug()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.6.13/src/Utility/Text.php#L1109). If your PHP installation supports it, then you may want to backport this, ie make use of [**PHPs transliteration functionality**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) provided by the INTL extension.